# Converting a javascript loop to be asynchronous and functional

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, functional-programming, es6-promise

I'm trying to make the following code more functional and asynchronous, but not having a lot of luck!

So the api calls can only take 5 id's at a time, which is why I created `splitListOfIds` and am looping through it.The second api call is dependent on the first api call

The code below works, but is slow and I get ESLINT errors with this code though and want to make it more functional and asynchronous. I've been trying to use Promises but not sure how to do it. Ideally want to get rid of the `for` loop.

```
const splitListOfIds = [
    [1,2,3,4,5],
    [6,7,8,9,10]
]

const allPolicies = []

for (let i = 0; i < splitListOfIds.length; i++) {
    const people = await peopleApi.getPeople(splitListOfIds[i])
    const policyIds = people.map(p => p.policyId)
    const policies = await policyApi.getPolicyDetails(policyIds)
    allPolicies.push(policies)
}
```

Comment: https://zellwk.com/blog/async-await-in-loops/

Comment: (You're already using promises btw)

Comment: If you're using `await` you're already using Promises. Any specific reason why you want to get rid of the for loop?

Comment: What do you mean by "more asynchronous"?

Comment: What linter errors are you getting?

Comment: When you say "can only take 5 id's at a time" do you mean the call only accepts 5 IDs at a time but you're allowed to do batches of 5 in parallel?

Comment: eslint gives me errors about it... says no await in a loop. Also a for loop is not asynchronous, is it?? unlike forEach which is asynchronous?

Comment: yes, the api only accepts a batch of 5 at a time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If this API allows you to do requests in parallel, you could take this kind of approach:

```
const allPolicies = await Promise.all(splitListOfIds.map(async peopleIds => {
  const people = await peopleApi.getPeople(peopleIds)
  const policyIds = people.map(p => p.policyId)
  const policies = await policyApi.getPolicyDetails(policyIds)
  return policies;
}));
```

Depending on what the APIs are doing in the background, this can get you in trouble if you've got too many things in parallel. If that's the case, then you need to implement some kind of max parallelism mechanism, something like this (untested, though there are probably libraries for this already):

```
async function processInParallel(maxParallelism, data, taskFn) {
  const results = [];
  const inFlight = new Set();  

  for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    while (inFlight.size >= maxParallelism) {
      // Wait for at least one to complete
      await Promise.race([...inFlight]);
    } 

    const task = taskFn(data[i]).then(result => {
      results.push(result);
      inFlight.delete(task);
    });
    inFlight.add(task);
  }

  await Promise.all([...inFlight]);

  return results;
}

// Usage
const allPolicies = await processInParallel(10, splitListOfIds, async peopleIds => {
  const people = await peopleApi.getPeople(peopleIds)
  const policyIds = people.map(p => p.policyId)
  const policies = await policyApi.getPolicyDetails(policyIds)
  return policies;
}));
```

Comment: that looks promising! let me try it and will accept your answer if it does the trick

Answer (score 3):

I would use **RxJs and Observable** to do this in an elegant way, for example

```
// Emit people ids as a sequence
const source = Rx.Observable.from([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]);
const subscribe = source
.bufferCount(5) // Buffer people ids to ensure the size won't exceed 5 for api calls
.flatMap(peopleIds => peopleApi.getPeople(peopleIds))
.map(people => people.map(user => user.policyId))
.flatMap(policyIds => policyApi.getPolicyDetails(policyIds))
.subscribe(policies => console.log(policies));
```

**Here is a snippet mocking your api**

```js
const mockPeople = [
  { "id": 1, "name": "Jack", "policyId": "p-01" },
  { "id": 2, "name": "Isobel", "policyId": "p-02" },
  { "id": 3, "name": "Steve", "policyId": "p-03" },
  { "id": 4, "name": "James", "policyId": "p-04" },
  { "id": 5, "name": "Marty", "policyId": "p-05" },
  { "id": 6, "name": "Janis", "policyId": "p-06" },
  { "id": 7, "name": "Annabel", "policyId": "p-07" },
  { "id": 8, "name": "Flora", "policyId": "p-08" },
  { "id": 9, "name": "Richard", "policyId": "p-09" },
]

const mockPolicies = [
  { "id": "p-01", "details": "Details for Jack's policy" },
  { "id": "p-02", "details": "Details for Isobel's policy" },
  { "id": "p-03", "details": "Details for Steve's policy" },
  { "id": "p-04", "details": "Details for James's policy" },
  { "id": "p-05", "details": "Details for Marty's policy" },
  { "id": "p-06", "details": "Details for Janis's policy" },
  { "id": "p-07", "details": "Details for Annabel's policy" },
  { "id": "p-08", "details": "Details for Flora's policy" },
  { "id": "p-09", "details": "Details for Richard's policy" }  
]

let mockGetPeople = async (peopleIds) => {
 let filteredPeople = mockPeople.filter(user => {
   return peopleIds.indexOf(user.id) !== -1;
  });
 return Promise.resolve(filteredPeople);
}
let mockGetPolicies = async (policyIds) => {
 let filteredPolicies = mockPolicies.filter(policy => {
   return policyIds.indexOf(policy.id) !== -1;
  });
 return Promise.resolve(filteredPolicies);
}


const source = Rx.Observable.from([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]);
const subscribe = source
.bufferCount(5)
.flatMap(peopleIds => mockGetPeople(peopleIds)) // mock of peopleApi.getPeople
.map(people => people.map(user => user.policyId))
.flatMap(policyIds => mockGetPolicies(policyIds)) // mock of policyApi.getPolicyDetails
.subscribe(policies => console.log(policies));
```

```html
<script src="https://npmcdn.com/@reactivex/rxjs@5.0.0-beta.8/dist/global/Rx.umd.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to `map` each async call to a Promise then await all of them together, like so:

```js
async function callAsync() {

    const asyncCalls = splitListOfIds.map(async function(pieceOfListOfIds) {

        const people = await peopleApi.getPeople(pieceOfListOfIds);
        const policyIds = people.map(p => p.policyId);
        const policies = await policyApi.getPolicyDetails(policyIds);

        allPolicies.push(policies);

    });

    await Promise.all(asyncCalls);
}
```

Basically every `async function` returns a `Promise` that you will collect in the `asyncCalls` array and then with `Promise.all` you wait for every Promise to settle.
If you just use `forEach` your program will continue execution without awaiting the various promises.

EDIT:

**Note:** this code will execute all the API calls in *parallel*

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong but there's no functional difference between yours and Jacobs right?

Comment: Yes, Jacob posted while I was writing. If this solution sutis your needs, please accept Jacob's answer, as he arrived first.